# How to change the output of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset like this

[image: dataset]

I try to encoding vocabulary with the following this code

```
def norm_vector(sentence, model, stopwords):
    vecs = [model[word.lower()] for word in word_tokenize(sentence) if word not in stopwords]  
    norm_vecs = [vec / np.linalg.norm(vec) for vec in vecs if np.linalg.norm(vec) > 0]
    sent_vecs = np.mean(norm_vecs, axis=0)
    return sent_vecs  

vecs_train_LV = [norm_vector(sentence, model_level, sw_indo) for sentence in data.data]
vecs_train_LV = np.array(vecs_train_LV)
vecs_train_LV
```

And the output of this code with following below:

```
array([array([-4.35138009e-02, -2.87008341e-02,  9.86183342e-03, -8.87360424e-02,
        1.83405634e-02, -6.50617108e-02, -6.65896460e-02,  8.60413313e-02,
       -5.40735014e-02, -9.36852470e-02,  4.09044847e-02,  1.15336493e-01],
      dtype=float32),
      array([-0.05026853, -0.02421026, -0.03221055, -0.14009777,  0.02021943,
       -0.02261522, -0.08134355,  0.12336601,  0.07266331, -0.10568545,
        0.00092218, -0.03538591], dtype=float32)],
      dtype=object)
```

But I want the output like this:

```
array([[-0.02279311,  0.04733656,  0.02461601, ...,  0.02087441,
        -0.04001932,  0.00982925],
       [-0.03176997, -0.02204693,  0.01420259, ..., -0.07120648,
        -0.05186931, -0.04976927],
       [-0.01539093, -0.00272909, -0.02494676, ..., -0.02440629,
         0.01618153, -0.05321534],
       ...,
       [-0.05358865,  0.01567019, -0.03903598, ...,  0.01297285,
        -0.02813709, -0.08277859],
       [-0.00991264,  0.0100073 ,  0.04893894, ..., -0.03793963,
        -0.01426407, -0.04612683],
       [ 0.01175337, -0.02632044, -0.04074009, ..., -0.00123112,
         0.03152793, -0.00567225]], dtype=float32)
```

How do I fix this situation? Because with the array output I can't do classification.

Thank you

Comment: `arr.astype(float)`

Comment: I have try but, still got the error

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the array constructor to stack your arrays but:

```
vecs_train_LV = np.r_[[norm_vector(sentence, model_level, sw_indo) for sentence in data.data]]
```

Or:

```
vecs_train_LV = np.vstack([norm_vector(sentence, model_level, sw_indo) for sentence in data.data])
```

Comment: When I use the code above, I got an error like this 
`ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 128 and the array at index 835 has size 1`



and when I use the code bottom, I still got the same output like `array([array([-4.35138009e-02, -2.87008341e-02,  9.86183342e-03, -8.87360424e-02,
        1.83405634e-02, -6.50617108e-02, -6.65896460e-02,  8.60413313e-02,......  `